# Library of human faces with tags for displayed emotions

Tags: data-request, images, faces

Is there an open dataset with images of human faces that's labeled with the emotion that the face displays?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of databases:

1. [The Extended Yale Face Database B](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~iskwak/ExtYaleDatabase/ExtYaleB.html) - It begins with the base name 'yaleB' and is followed by the two digit number signifying the subject number and then by the two digit number signifying the pose. The rest of the filename deals with the azimuth and elevation of the single light source direction.
2. [Japanese Female Facial Expression (JAFFE) (1998)](http://www.kasrl.org/jaffe_info.html) - Ten expressors posed 3 or 4 examples of each of the six basic facial expressions (happiness, sadness, surprise, anger, disgust, fear) [4](https://www.behance.net/gallery/10675283/Facial-Expression-Public-Databases) and a neutral face for a total of 219 images of facial expressions.
3. [Karolinska Directed Emotional Faces (KDEF) (1998)](http://www.emotionlab.se/resources/kdef) - The Karolinska Directed Emotional Faces is a set of totally 4900 pictures of human facial expressions of emotion. The set contains 70 individuals, each displaying 7 different emotional expressions, each expression being photographed (twice) from 5 different angles.

These were pulled [Behance Facial Expression Public Databases](https://www.behance.net/gallery/10675283/Facial-Expression-Public-Databases), there are more, but went through and pulled the ones that I identified as matching your request and could be readily downloaded. These are all for non-commercial use and additional data sets are available upon request.

One interesting thing the researchers noted is whether the person was told to have an emotion or actually emoting through an external stimuli.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a set of pictures that contain only the face part of the human head (no or even background), i.e. frontal upright images (like below)-
[image: frontal upright imagese]
then you may check images of [LFWcrop Face Dataset](http://conradsanderson.id.au/lfwcrop/)(cropped version of the Labeled Faces in the Wild (LFW) dataset, keeping only the center portion of each image i.e. the face), [frontal images manually aligned part 1,2](http://fei.edu.br/~cet/facedatabase.html)

Comment: I can see that the images are labeled with names but from where do I get the emotions?